# How to fire ItemCommand argument child repeater in nested repeater control in c#.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater, asprepeater, nested-repeater

Here is my aspx page code for nested repeater..

```
<asp:Repeater ID="repAccordian" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="repAccordian_ItemDataBound" onitemcommand="repAccordian_ItemCommand">
    <ItemTemplate>
    <%#Eval("TopicName")%>
    <asp:Label ID="lbltopicid" runat="server" Visible="false" Text='<%#Eval("TopicID")%>' </asp:Label>
    <div>
    <asp:Repeater ID="repsubtopic" runat="server"><ItemTemplate>
    <%#Eval("SubTopicName")%>                              
    <a href='' class='click'>
    <asp:Label ID="lblView" CommandName="View" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("SubTopicID") %>'
     runat="server" Text="View" /></a>
    </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
    </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

i need to fire ItemCommand argument when click on view in child repeater(repsubtopic).. 
pls give me suggestions to solve this problem.

Comment: Then define a `onitemcommand="repsubtopic_ItemCommand"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Tim suggested

```
<asp:Repeater ID="repsubtopic" runat="server" 
      onitemcommand="repsubtopic_ItemCommand">
```

and define `repsubtopic_ItemCommand` in your code behind.

Comment: protected void repsubtopic_ItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            int subid = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
            

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
    }